# no permission to redefine imported_procedure 'lists:union prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

im trying to define a predicate in prolog that would return the union of two sets but im facing the following error.

```
set_operations:-
    write('write 1 for union:'), nl,
    read(X),
    (X=1->
      write('enter club 1:'),nl,
      read(Y),
      write('Enter club 2:'),nl,
      read(Z),
      union(Y,Z)).

club(football, [john, mary, peter, jane]).
club(basketball, [peter, jane, tom, kim]).
club(dance,[emily, andrew, john, jacob]).


union(Club1,Club2,R):-Club(Club1,L1), Club(Club2,L2),         
                    concatenate(L1,L2,X), sort(X,R).

concatenate( [ ] , [ ] , [ ] ).
concatenate( [ ] , X , X ).
concatenate( X ,[], X ).
concatenate( [H1|T1] , L2, [H1|X] ):-concatenate(T1,L2,X).
```

Comment: You have `Club(Club1,L1)` instead of `club(Club1,L1)`

Comment: Your code calls a `union/2` predicate but defines instead a `union/3` predicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you had corrected both the problems pinpointed by @brebs and @PauloMora, you still need to add the following [directive](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=redefine_system_predicate/1):

```
:- redefine_system_predicate(union/3).
```

or rename your predicate to something like `myunion`, to avoid the problem altogheter. Here is a possible implementation, simpler than your, based on append/3 followed by sort/2:

```
myunion(L1,L2,U) :- append(L1,L2,T),sort(T,U).
```